# Función para buscar y mostrar cookies por nombre con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo varias cookies en donde el nombre empieza con "Esp_" quisiera poder buscar las cookies que empiecen con Esp_ y mostrar su valor.

¿Como puedo hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con esto:

```
    var match = document.cookie.match(/Esp_/g);
    match.forEach(function(match, index) { console.log(match); });
```

pero me devulve solo la cadema "Esp_" y quiero que me devuelva toda la cadena, nombre y valor.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Por favor sube el código que has intentado , para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder.
He intentado con esto:
    var match = document.cookie.match(/Esp_/g);
    match.forEach(function(match, index) {
        console.log(match);

    });

pero me devulve solo la cadema "Esp_" y quiero que me devuelva toda la cadena, nombre y valor.

Comment: Esto que pusiste como comentario tienes que ponerlo en el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que no se puede resolver con una sola expresión regular si las coincidencias que buscamos no son consecutivas.

Entonces dependerá como quieres el resultado final, pero en principio puedes hacer `.split("; ")` para obtener un array de todas las cookies y luego un `.filter()` de `.test()` evaluando que comience con *Esp_*:

```
const res = document.cookie.split("; ").filter(c=>/^Esp_.+/.test(c))
.map(e=>e.split("="));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Gracias, esto era exactamente lo que buscaba. Gracias también por la explicación de como lo hiciste, entendí perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

**Hola!!**
Contame si te sirve éste código, configuralo con un loop o ciclo en el que busque todas las cookis con ese inicio en el nombre.

```html
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```